# Find row with multiple search criteria on substrings in VBA

Tags: vba, excel, search

I need to find the row where a cell in column `B` contains two substrings.

For example these Strings in `B1:B3`

```
A string with Cows
Cows and stuff
A string with Chickens
```

I need to find the row `B2`where the 2 substrings `Cows` and `shit` are present.

What i tried so far:

1. Find formula that doesent do multiple search criteria. :(
2. `=MATCH(1;INDEX((B:B="Cows")*(B:B="shit"););)` that doesent do substrings
3. A lot other stuff i forgot,

If it is possible i would like a pure VBA solution.

Any ideas on this one?

Comment: You could use an If statement with two times an INSTR. For info on INSTR see http://www.techonthenet.com/excel/formulas/instr.php Combine criteria within your ifstatement with the word And.

Comment: And ofcourse nest that in a For loop in which you loop over all rows.

Answer (score 0):

http://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/74933-matching-multiple-criteria-visual-basic-applications.html This is what you are looking for with your MATCH function.

Answer (score 0):

The below will assign all values within column B to an array, and then assess each element of the array to see if it contains the strings "Cows" and "excrement".

To assess the string within the element, we use the [`InStr()` Function](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8460tsh1(v=vs.90).aspx).

```
Sub findStrings()
    Dim wb As Workbook, ws As Worksheet
    Dim arrValues() As Variant
    Dim lrow As Long, i As Long

    Set wb = ThisWorkbook
    Set ws = wb.Sheets(1)
    lrow = ws.Cells(Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row

    arrValues = Range(Cells(1, 2), Cells(lrow, 2))

    For i = 1 To UBound(arrValues, 1)
        If InStr(1, arrValues(i, 1), "Cows") Then
            If InStr(1, arrValues(i, 1), "excrement") Then
                MsgBox ("Cell " & Cells(i, 2).Address & " contains both strings.")
                Exit Sub
            End If
        End If
    Next i
End Sub
```

This will only find 1 match containing the strings you specify, if you require further matches then you will need a different solution.

Answer (score 0):

This function returns range that contains all the cells having in its content both words given as parameters:

```
Public Function findCellsWithWords(firstWord As String, secondWord As String) As Excel.Range
    Dim wks As Excel.Worksheet
    Dim rng As Excel.Range
    Dim rngFirst As Excel.Range
    Dim rngSecond As Excel.Range
    '--------------------------------------------------


    Set wks = Excel.ActiveSheet
    Set rng = wks.Columns(2).EntireColumn

    Set rngFirst = findAll(rng, firstWord)
    Set rngSecond = findAll(rng, secondWord)


    Set findCellsWithWords = Excel.Intersect(rngFirst, rngSecond)


End Function


Public Function findAll(rng As Excel.Range, what As Variant) As Excel.Range
    Dim rngResult As Excel.Range
    Dim found As Excel.Range
    Dim firstFound As String
    '----------------------------------------------------------------------------

    With rng

        Set found = rng.Find(what)


        Do Until found Is Nothing

            If rngResult Is Nothing Then
                firstFound = found.Address
                Set rngResult = found
            Else
                Set rngResult = Excel.Union(rngResult, found)
            End If


            'Find next occurrence.
            Set found = .FindNext(found)
            If found.Address = firstFound Then Exit Do

        Loop

    End With


    Set findAll = rngResult


End Function
```